How to properly organize chains of states in aiogram 3
So, I'm interested to know: is there any more practical way to organize chains of states than the one I suggested below?
Some commands in my bot, such as unlock and about, imply performing the same function at the beginning: getting the user Id, but the first command requires going to the next step, but the second one does not require anything else and just sends a message to the administrator.
I thought about how the get_id function would not be duplicated for different chains and it turned out what I suggest below (I can write telegram bots and what I'm asking here is just a research experiment)
handlers.py
from .chains import AdminStates
from .objects import User, Chain

class AdminHandlers:
    router = Router()
    states = AdminStates()
    chain = None

    @router.message(states.get_id)
    async def get_id(message: Message, state: FSMContext) -> None:
        text = message.text
        await message.answer(text)

        next_state = AdminHandlers.chain.next_state()
        if next_state is None:
            await state.clear()
            await state.set_state(AdminHandlers.states.chat)
        else:
            await state.set_state(next_state)

    @router.message(Command("about"))
    async def command_about_handler(message: Message, state: FSMContext) -> None:
        user = User(message)
        await user.intitialize()
        if user.is_admin:
            AdminHandlers.chain = Chain([AdminHandlers.states.get_id])
            await state.set_state(AdminHandlers.chain.next_state())

objects.py
from aiogram.fsm.state import State

class Chain:
    def __init__(self, states: list[State]) -> State | None:
        self.iterator = iter(states)
        self.position = 0
        self.len = len(states)

    def next_state(self) -> None:
        if self.position < self.len:
            self.position += 1
            return next(self.iterator)
        return None

P.S.:
I would just like to know your opinion about this approach to the organization of handlers (in the form of classes) and chains of states in this form
